# Can one OnevsRest classifier from sklearn be used for obtaining binary classification results?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I am currently using `sklearn` [OnevsRest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) classifier on a dataset. The observations of my datasets are describing actual mammals and the columns of the datasets are some mammals features.

All mammals that are not felines are in class '0'. Different kind of felines are in classes from 1 to 4. When I compute the AUC for the class '0' (mammals vs. rest) I get an precision close to 1.

However, when I run the binary detection on my dataset with all mammals that are not felines are in class '0', and all kinds of feline are in class '1', I get a AUC close to 0 (with either `'y_score = clf.predict_proba(Xtest)[:,0]' or 'y_score = clf.predict_proba(Xtest)[:,1]'`).

Should both AUC I am referring to be similar (because 1vsall consists in several binary classifiers)? I can give a code example if needed but really I am only looking for a clarification regarding the theory.